# JUnit won't stop at breakpoints in Eclipse (using JDK 1.6.0.20)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit, breakpoints

my breakpoints in Eclipse won't stop the execution of a JUnit test. It doesn't matter where I set the breakpoint in the JUnit method, it simply won't stop the code from flowing. Placing it in a class called in the JUnit test won't work either.

I am using the JDK in the version of 1.6.0.20, so I guess I'm not affected by the bug in version 1.6.0.14.

Do you know any hints concerning this matter?

Comment: Maybe try adding `System.out.println("---- TEST DEBUG");` first and see if this is printed in the Console. If not then that part is never called.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should start your unit-tests with `Debug as > JUnit test`

Comment: I am doing this and it is still not stopping.

Answer (score 14):

If your break points appear with a back slash across, you have to go to the debug perspective (Window → Open perspective) and in the ‘Breakpoints’ window, unselect the ‘Skip all break points’ button (circle with backslash across)

Comment: You are a real lifesaver.

Comment: There should really be a tooltip that appears when you hoover over the backslashed breakpoint that tells you it is being skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Plese use

```
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

in debug configuration > VM arguments section

Comment: Still not stopping with this option

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem today and for me the reason was pure stupidity – if the unit test outputs something to the console at first and throws an exception afterwards, both before reaching the breakpoint, you do not see the exception in eclipse's debug perspective because it gets printed in the JUnit view, but the output before switched away from that view to the Console output.

Answer (score 0):

There's likely an error in your test which is preventing JUnit from getting to the thing you're trying to test. JUnit doesn't like to show these errors. Try removing lines from your unit tests until they start to work, or put breakpoints inside the methods your unit test is calling.